# Writing an XML File on Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I need to perform a custom xml format from a set of objects, and download it into the client. All the xml conversion is implemented in an string, but i couldn't find a way to make it downloadble

Answer (score 1):

You can change the content-type of a Visualforce page, so setting that to text/xml but that still wouldn't necessarily force the browser to display a Save dialog, as far as I'm aware that tends to be browser implementation dependant.

Based on some quick Duck-Duck-Going I've seen a few people suggest that if a browser doesn't know a file's format then it'll ask you do download and this can be forced using the content-type `"application/octet-stream"`, so maybe this is worth a go:

```
<apex:Page contentType="application/octet-stream" ..etc.. >
```

Not sure what the impact would be on the downloaded file though!